# Redirections shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script

Can anyone explain the following?

```
:~$ ls macreave.sh fgvdvg > testo 2> testo
:~$ cat testo 
macreave.sh 
ccess fgvdvg: No such file or directory 

:~$ ls macreave.sh fgvdvg > testo 2>&1
:~$ cat testo 
ls: cannot access fgvdvg: No such file or directory 
macreave.sh
```

Doing it the first way it eats the first few characters of the error message, the second way shows it just fine. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the second command

```
:~$ ls macreave.sh fgvdvg > testo 2>&1
```

you will cause the stderr ouput of `ls` to be written to the same filedescriptor than stdout (`2>&1`) and the stdout to the file `testo`: so you have a unique *flux* that finish in your file.

With the first command instead

```
ls macreave.sh fgvdvg > testo 2> testo
```

you are redirecting independently to the same file `testo`. The problem is pipings and redirections can be asyncronus (see [this answer too](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182232/pipes-how-do-data-flow-in-a-pipeline?rq=1)); you have 2 fluxes that finish in your file both recreating it.

It seems that:

- the faster was the stderror (for few bytes) that creates a file `testo` (`>`) and write inside *ls: cannot a*
- then it is arrived the stdout that recreates the same file (`>`) erasing what inside and puts the output *macreave.sh*
- finally it is arrived the second part of stderr that writes in the file what remains *ccess fgvdvg: No such file or directory*.

Maybe if you execute again you will have a different result.

References

- [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections)
- [Pipes, how do data flow in a pipeline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182232/pipes-how-do-data-flow-in-a-pipeline?rq=1)