# redirection - why it doesn't work this way

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, centos, shell-script

I know there are 3 streams attached to a process when it is run namely the input, output and error stream.

And redirection execution work from left to right.

I intend to execute a command, redirect its output stream to a file and its error stream to the same file as well.

-- nofile does not exists, text1 file does exists

```
head nofile text1 1> output.txt 2> output.txt  -- I know this won't work.

head nofile text1 1> output.txt 2>&1 -- while this will work, passing the error stream to the output ste
```

q1) Why ?

If it is a matter of "it is suppose to be written this way"   then why can't the below work as well

```
head nofile text1 2>&1 1> output.txt
head nofile text1 2>&1> output.txt
```

On the above i am redirecting the error stream to output stream, the output stream to the file. Its logic is the same as the above.

Comment: I read this `2>&1` as "redirect file descriptor 2 to *the thing that fd 1 currently points to*" -- this makes it easier to understand why `2>&1 1>file` means that stderr does not get redirected to file

Comment: There is a nice illustrated tutorial at [Illustrated Redirection Tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial) which makes this easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer #1: *Race* conflict**

- > head nofile text1 1> output.txt 2> output.txt    # -- <strike>I know this won't work.</strike>`

This actually works, even if not as you expected and doesn't comply  your purpose.
You have 2 file-descriptors that will be redirected independently to the same output file with `> output.txt`.
One file-descriptor will act faster: it will create the output.txt file and it will start to write inside it.
When the second file-descriptor will start to act, it will recreate the same file (`> output.txt`), erasing what inside.
You will lose the first part written by the first file-descriptor, if there is any.
Expect a garbled output especially with long outputs. See this [answer too](https://superuser.com/a/937494/257269).
Consider that the behaviour is not always reproducible. On my system, today, the file is created with the error inside as a first line and the text after.

- > head nofile text1 1> output.txt 2>&1   # ok this works

This works because first you change the redirection for standard output to the file `output.txt`. Then you ask to redirect the standard error to the same *destination* of the standard output, that means the file `output.txt`.

**Answer #2: Order matters**
The *core* of the answer: *bash* redirecting *is no commutative* it means that *orders matter*:

> head nofile text1 2>&1 1> output.txt
>   head nofile text1 2>&1> output.txt

Here before you ask to redirect the *standard error* to the *standard output* destination (probably the current *tty*). Then you ask to change *only the standard output* to the output file `output.txt`. (both command `1>output.txt` and `>output.txt` act in the same way). The *standard error* remain redirected where it was before (probably the current *tty*).